# how to compare two objects present in same array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are two different objects in single array, i have to compare these array if the values are different then i have to get the Array1 value

```
Array1.push({
    "Name": "Max",
    "Occupation": "Agri",
    "Location": "KGP" 
});

Array2.push({
    "Name": "Alex",
    "Occupation": "S.E",
    "Location": "Mut" 
});
```

Comment: You can't compare objects directly. You need to compare their properties.

Comment: ok how could i compare the properties

Comment: You need to iterate that array using any loop and then you can compare the properties which you want.

Comment: can you show me how..?

Comment: Ok so you want to compare the value of "Name" properties ?

Comment: The linked question has some answers and discussion of this topic, which can also be found in a lot of other questions.

Comment: i have to compare all the properties ..

Answer (score 1):

You can compare Like below:

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var foo = [];
var i = 0;
jQuery.grep(array2, function(el) {

    if (jQuery.inArray(el, array1) == -1) foo.push(el);


    i++;

});


alert(" the difference is " + foo);
```

Comment: sorry , it works for the above given code, but for my code it doesn't works

Comment: There are lot of answer available for same, so it would be better if you share your complete code then we can help more.

Comment: Array1.push({
    "Name": "Max",
    "Occupation": "Agri",
    "Location": "KGP" 
});

Array2.push({
    "Name": "Alex",
    "Occupation": "S.E",
    "Location": "KGP" 
});

in the above arrays i have different values in properties Name and Occupation but the location have the same value as that of Array1,

Comment: here i want to get Name and Occupation properties (which is different)

Comment: we have to compare the two arrays and  
here i want to get Name and Occupation properties (which is different)